# GUI shows elements only after dragging window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

```
        frame_ref = new Frame("Login");
        mainPanel_ref = new Panel();
        buttonPanel_ref = new Panel();
        grid_ref = new GridLayout(4,2);
        frame_ref.setSize(300,120);
        frame_ref.setVisible(true);

        email_ref = new TextField();
        password_ref = new JPasswordField();

        mainPanel_ref.setLayout(grid_ref);
        mainPanel_ref.add(new Label("E-Mail"));
        mainPanel_ref.add(email_ref);
        mainPanel_ref.add(new Label("Passwort"));
        mainPanel_ref.add(password_ref);

        mainPanel_ref.add(submitLogin_ref);
        mainPanel_ref.add(fehlerMeldung_ref);

        frame_ref.add(mainPanel_ref);
```

I set up a view in Java like above. The window is complete empty, but after I drag and drop its size, all the elements appear. Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `frame_ref.setVisible(true);` after `frame_ref.add(mainPanel_ref);`.

What happens here is: You show frame by calling `frame_ref.setVisible(true);` and then add elements in it. So you get an empty frame. Afterwards when you drag or resize it gets repainted and you can see elements.

Comment: or call revalidate() and repaint() after adding the mainPanel_ref

Comment: @StanislavL: that is not proper solution. You should display your frame after completely adding stuffs into it not before it and then add stuffs and then call repaint().

Comment: `pack()` or `validate()` should be called at during GUI creation.  (This answer may work, but it is not the *entire* answer.)

Answer (score 9):

Call `pack()` on the `JFrame` after the components have been added. Doing so will cause the frame to assume the smallest size it needs to display the components.  Finally call (`setLocation()`(4) &) `setVisible(true)`.

[image: Login Frame]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

class FrameTest {

    public void init() {
        frame_ref = new JFrame("Login");
        frame_ref.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainPanel_ref = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2,6,3));
        mainPanel_ref.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));

        email_ref = new JTextField();
        password_ref = new JPasswordField();
        mainPanel_ref.add(new JLabel("E-Mail"));
        mainPanel_ref.add(email_ref);
        mainPanel_ref.add(new JLabel("Passwort"));
        mainPanel_ref.add(password_ref);

        mainPanel_ref.add(new JLabel(""));
        mainPanel_ref.add(new JLabel(""));
        mainPanel_ref.add(submitLogin_ref);
        mainPanel_ref.add(fehlerMeldung_ref);

        frame_ref.add(mainPanel_ref);

        //frame_ref.setSize(300,120);
        frame_ref.pack();
        frame_ref.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FrameTest().init();
            }
        });
    }

    private JFrame frame_ref;
    private JPanel mainPanel_ref;
    private JTextField email_ref;
    private JPasswordField password_ref;
    private JButton submitLogin_ref = new JButton("Submit Login");
    private JButton fehlerMeldung_ref = new JButton("Fehler Meldung");
}
```

#### Other tips:

1. Don't mix Swing with AWT.  At least, not the components, or not before targeting Java 7+.
2. A log-in component is often better suited to putting in a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` rather than a `JFrame`.
3. This might be better suited to a nested layout, or some other layout than `GridLayout`
4. `setLocation()` might be swapped out for:

   - If the log-in has a 'parent' component, `setLocationRelativeTo(Component)`.
   - If the log-in is the first screen visible, `setLocationByPlatform(true)` (1.6+).
5. Check the source closely for other tips.
6. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @mKorbel  At first I was going to say *"Don't code using AWT components in this millennium"*.  It was only when making an SSCCE that I noticed the `JPasswordField`! ;)